# Easy way to determine whether bottom side of M.2 module is populated?

Tags: m.2, dimensions

When buying an M.2 module it's sometimes important to know if the bottom side of the module has any components on it because of height constraints.

In [a quick reference](http://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=1-1773702-1NGFFQRG-EN&DocType=DS&DocLang=EN) to M.2 referenced by the M.2 Wikipedia article a "Module Nomenclature" is described:

> Example: Type 2242-D2-B-M
>
> Used for double slot module cards

According to that document, the second part of the number – ´D2´ – describes whether the module has components on one or both sides (I'm assuming the "D" stands for double-sided). But then it says this number is only "used for double slot module cards". Why is that?

So if I want to buy a single slot module, like B or M, that means I can't read my way to knowing if there are components on the bottom side. Or is there some other way to easily tell? Most modules I've seen only specifies the first part, e.g. "2280".

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in assuming that D2 refers to double sided. As for knowing if a specific card is single or double sided then the retailer might not give that information but the product maker should so look the module up on the producers website. And be advised also that to use a double sided M.2 you need a higher connector on your motherboard, the single sided connectors are only around 2 mm high but the double sided connectors are at least 3 mm high.

See [this presentation](https://sata-io.org/sites/default/files/documents/M2_Webcast_Slides.pdf) for example.